# Expected gain by playing a game

Tags: probability

I'm flipping three coins. If all three are the same (all heads or all tails) then I will get 10 dollars and I may finish the game. If it is not the case then I might ask to flip any number of the coins again (to flip one of them or two of them again, etc.). What's the expected gain by playing this game?

Is the answer 7.5 or did I make a mistake?

Comment: You can only ask to flip again once?

Comment: Seems valid. The optimal strategy is to re-flip only one coin, the one with the minority side showing.

Comment: If you can flip a coin infinitely times then the expected value is $10$.

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 possibilities for your first flip:

```
TTT TTH THT THH
HTT HTH HHT HHH
```

$2/8$ times you will get 3 times the same side on your first flip. Note that in all other cases you have $2$ of one side and $1$ of the other side. That means that if you ask to re-flip the singular coin you have a $50\%$ chance to make all three the same, which is the best you can do.

So your total expected gain is $10 \cdot(\frac28 + \frac68 \cdot \frac12) = \frac{50}{8} = 6.25$.